# Copy all files under specific directory name format in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have translation files under a t9n directory throughout my app...in some component directories, etc.

```
app
components
    ComponentA
        t9n
            translations_A.json
    ComponentB
        t9n
            translations_B.json
t9n
    common-translations.json
```

And I'm looking to create a grunt task to copy all those .json files into an `assets` directory when the app is built.

Is there a way to grab all contents under specific directory names? So that I could say....for every directory under app, grab the contents of any `t9n` directory?

I know you can do things like...

`"**/*.{png}"` to say copy all PNG files....but not sure what it would be for the above.

Comment: Do you mean `app/**/t9n/*.{json}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is like mentioned in the comments, `"app/**/t9n/*.json` particularly I was confused on what globbing patterns were with Grunt https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns

I ended up using the files array format from the grunt documentation https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-array-format

and ended up with something like this...

```
  "build-t9n": {
    files: [
      {
        cwd: "src/app/js",
        src: ["**/t9n/*.json"],
        dest: "build/assets/t9n",
        expand: true
      }
    ]
  }
```